# Set up ns1, ns2 name servers at google cloud from a registered name server

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dns-zone

I have regestered ns1.grant-fullen.com and ns2.grant-fullen.com and (Proper IPS) at namecheap.com

I am using google cloud dns.
I have set up A records at google cloud dns.

ns1.grant-fullen.com.   A   300 35.231.125.190

ns2.grant-fullen.com.   A   300 35.231.125.190

Problem I am haveing is with CWP7 web panel.
Can not start the DNS BIND service

.Warning for this is

```
Mar 31 22:26:38 centos7 bash[3667]: zone nf1j.com/IN: loaded serial 2019033167
Mar 31 22:26:38 centos7 bash[3667]: zone grantfullen.com/IN: loaded serial 2019033168
Mar 31 22:26:38 centos7 bash[3667]: zone grant-fullen.com/IN: NS 'ns1.grant-fullen.com' has no address records (A or AAAA)
Mar 31 22:26:38 centos7 bash[3667]: zone grant-fullen.com/IN: NS 'ns2.grant-fullen.com' has no address records (A or AAAA)
Mar 31 22:26:38 centos7 bash[3667]: zone grant-fullen.com/IN: not loaded due to errors.
Mar 31 22:26:38 centos7 bash[3667]: _default/grant-fullen.com/IN: bad zone
Mar 31 22:26:38 centos7 systemd[1]: named.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Mar 31 22:26:38 centos7 systemd[1]: Failed to start Berkeley Internet Name Domain (DNS).
Mar 31 22:26:38 centos7 systemd[1]: Unit named.service entered failed state.
Mar 31 22:26:38 centos7 systemd[1]: named.service failed.
```

Question:= DO I have something configured wrong in the a records at google cloud dns ?

Comment: Your zone file has syntax errors.  You can check syntax with `named-checkzone example.com /path/to/example.com/zonefile`

Comment: The logs you posted tell you what the problem is and exactly how to fix it.

Comment: I have a records for the ns1, ns2. I do not know if this is correct     grant-fullen.com. A 300 
35.231.125.190
grant-fullen.com. NS 21600 
ns-cloud-d1.googledomains.com.
ns-cloud-d2.googledomains.com.
ns-cloud-d3.googledomains.com.
ns-cloud-d4.googledomains.com.
grant-fullen.com. SOA 21600 
ns-cloud-d1.googledomains.com. cloud-dns-hostmaster.google.com. 1 21600 3600 259200 300
ns1.grant-fullen.com. A 300 
35.231.125.190
ns2.grant-fullen.com. A 300 
35.231.125.190
srv1.grant-fullen.com. A 300 
35.231.125.190
www.grant-fullen.com. CNAME 300 
grant-fullen.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verifying the IPs, you don't have any problem with google cloud DNS configuration.
Your domains are resolving with the correct IP as you configured.

### ----------------------

*dig ns1.grant-fullen.com

; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Ubuntu <<>> ns1.grant-fullen.com

;; global options: +cmd

;; Got answer:

;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 58018

;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:

; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512

;; QUESTION SECTION:

;ns1.grant-fullen.com.          IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:

**ns1.grant-fullen.com.   299     IN      A       35.231.125.190**

;; Query time: 28 msec

;; SERVER: 169.254.169.254#53(169.254.169.254)

;; WHEN: Tue Apr 02 21:10:13 UTC 2019

;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 65*

### ----------------------

*dig ns2.grant-fullen.com

; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Ubuntu <<>> ns2.grant-fullen.com

;; global options: +cmd

;; Got answer:

;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 7204

;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:

; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512

;; QUESTION SECTION:

;ns2.grant-fullen.com.          IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:

**ns2.grant-fullen.com.   299     IN      A       35.231.125.190**

;; Query time: 166 msec

;; SERVER: 169.254.169.254#53(169.254.169.254)

;; WHEN: Tue Apr 02 21:10:28 UTC 2019

;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 65*

Also you cant try with the IP (35.231.125.190) itself at a web browser and this will take you to the CWP7 web panel.
The logs you posted are related to to the DNS BIND service running at centos7, and it's telling you that you need to add a record (A or AAAA) for both domains (ns1.grant-fullen.com and ns2.grant-fullen.com)
and that there is a problem with the zone you configured.

I found this guide that maybe can be useful for you (https://www.linuxtechi.com/install-configure-cwp-centos-web-panel-on-centos-7/)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I got the bind server going.